# Maximum average departmental salary

Tags: mysql, sql

i have employee and department table i need to find maximum average departmental salary.We can have two more than 1 maximum value.I tried the following query

```
select dept.name,avg(employee.sal)
from employee,dept
where dept.id=empolyee.id
group by dept.name
LIMIT 1
```

however i can manage only one maximum average salary, how can i get query more than one maximum value

Comment: should there be `ORDER BY AVG(employee.sal) DESC` in the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join with another query that gets the maximum average, then return all the rows with the same average.

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.avgSal
FROM (SELECT d.name, avg(e.sal) AS avgSal
      FROM employee AS e
      JOIN dept AS d ON d.id = e.dept_id
      GROUP BY d.name) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT d.name, avg(e.sal) AS avgSal
      FROM employee AS e
      JOIN dept AS d ON d.id = e.dept_id
      GROUP BY d.name
      ORDER BY avgSal DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t2
ON t1.avgSal = t2.avgSal
```